# JavaScript Convert Names to Uppercase, Except Mc/Mac/etc

Tags: javascript

Everything I can find by searching is people wanting to convert to sentence/title case from lower/upper/random case. That's the opposite of my problem.

What I have is already correct, I want to convert it to uppercase except for the "c" or "ac" etc. So McDonald becomes McDONALD, MacDonald becomes MacDONALD, etc.

Probably the best way is separating out the lower-case letters that occur between two upper-case letters, either before or after running toUpperCase(), but my brain is fried at the moment so I'm not sure how to go about it.

It's for an After Effects expression, controlling the display so I can have sentence case in one composition and upper case in another, from the same source layer. So I know input will be perfect.

Comment: What are the `..etc` conditions?

Comment: can you give an example of how you want the output to be so i can come up with some snippet

Comment: etc is just other names in the same format. McLeod, DeVille, McIntosh, McCallum...any name with the kind of "prefix" formatting. Not always "Mac" or "Mc" necessarily...but at the same time excluding Mack, Mackinnon, Mace, and so forth.

Comment: if input is 'cam' or 'acam' what will be output ?

Comment: DeVille, doesnt have c or ac. we first need to establish the pattern

Comment: Output is literally just the name, as described in the question.

Comment: The pattern, as described in the question, is lowercase letter(s) sandwiched between uppercase letters, with no spaces. I can't think of anything that would break that, off the top of my head. So McDonald has a lowercase c between two uppercase letters, DeVille a lowercase e, MacDonald a lowercase ac, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
const input = "MacDonald";

const matches = input.match(/([A-Z][a-z]*)/g);

const output = matches.length > 1 ? 
  matches.reduce((acc, match, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      return match;
    }
    return acc + match.toUpperCase();
  }) :
  input.toUpperCase();
```

First we take the `input` apart by matching it against a simple regular expression. The `match` method in the example will return `["Mac","Donald"]`.

Then, if there is only one match, we return it in uppercase.

In case of multiple matches, we construct the result by concatenating uppercase parts except for the first part.

Here's a version for a whole sentence:

```
const input = "Old MacDonald is a fine man.";

const output = input
  .split(/\s/)
  .map(word => {

    const matches = word.match(/([A-Z][a-z]*)/g);

    if (!matches || matches.length === 1) {
        return word.toUpperCase();
    }

    return matches.reduce((acc, match, index) => {
      return index === 0 ? match : acc + match.toUpperCase();
    });
  })
  .join(' ');

// output == "OLD MacDONALD IS A FINE MAN."
```

Comment: Could you add some comments/explanation of what each step is doing?

Comment: Does this work if it's not the only/first word? ie if it was a full name?

Comment: It works only for a single word. I'll edit to add another version, just a moment.

Comment: There's an error in line 5 of the sentence version.

Comment: "> does not have a value".

Comment: The arrow function syntax may be too much for AfterEffects (haven't tried myself) so try to substitute that with a regular function: `function (word) {...`. Then of course, the same goes to the function inside `reduce`.

Comment: Could you edit that into your example? I'm not quite sure what to change. All I can manage to do is shift the error to different lines...

Comment: Seems map() and reduce() won't work either, and I wanted to all-caps only the last match rather than all but the first, so I wrote my own code based off your structure. Posted it as an answer myself if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Sami Hult's answer covers most of the bases, but unfortunately refuses to work in After Effects due to syntax issues and map() and reduce() not being supported, and I wanted to make one small tweak, all-capsing only the last portion rather than all but the first (to account for a possible double prefix).

So based on that code, I came up with this:

```js
function str_uppercase(str) {
    str = str.split(/\s/);
    var output = [];

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var word = str[i];
        var matches = word.match(/([A-Z][a-z]*)/g);

        if (!matches || matches.length === 1) {
            word = word.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            var x = matches.length - 1;
            matches[x] = matches[x].toUpperCase();
            word = matches.join('');
        }

        output.push(word);
    }

    return output.join(' ');
}

console.log(str_uppercase('Old MacMcDonald Had a farm'));
// => OLD MacMcDONALD HAD A FARM
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably be to keep a list of prefixes and test if the word starts with one of these:

```js
//Prefixes to look for
var prefixToKeep = [
    "Mac",
    "Mc"
];
//Selective uppercase function
function selectiveUpperCase(text) {
    //Find words by wordBoundaries
    return text.replace(/\b\w+\b/gim, function (word) {
        //Test for prefixes
        for (var prefixToKeepIndex = 0; prefixToKeepIndex < prefixToKeep.length; prefixToKeepIndex++) {
            var prefix = prefixToKeep[prefixToKeepIndex];
            if (word.indexOf(prefix) === 0) {
                //prefix matches. Return prefix as is + rest of the word in uppercase
                return word.slice(0, prefix.length) + word.slice(prefix.length).toUpperCase();
            }
        }
        //No prefix found, return word as uppercase
        return word.toUpperCase();
    });
}
//TEST
var text = "Old MacDonald had a farm\nE-I-E-I-O\nAnd on this farm he had a cow\nE-I-E-I-O\nWith a moo-moo here\nAnd a moo-moo there\nHere a moo, there a moo\nEverywhere a moo-moo\nOld MacDonald had a farm\nE-I-E-I-O ";
console.log(selectiveUpperCase(text));
```

**EDIT 1 - Upper-Lower-Upper Test**

In response to the comments, this newer version tests for Upper-Lower-Upper cases and uses its findings to determine which parts to uppercase.

```js
//Selective uppercase function
function selectiveUpperCase(text) {
    //Find words by wordBoundaries
    return text.replace(/\b\w+\b/gim, function (word) {
        var reg = /[A-Z]+[a-z]+[A-Z]\w+/gm;
        //Test for Upper-Lower-Upper combo
        if (reg.test(word) || reg.test(word)) {
            //start at index 1
            var l = 0;
            while (l++ < word.length) {
                //move up the word and test for an uppercase letter
                if (word[l] === word[l].toUpperCase()) {
                    break;
                }
                l++;
                //return the first slice (the prefix) as is and uppercase the rest
                return word.slice(0, l) + word.slice(l).toUpperCase();
            }
        }
        //No prefix found, return word as uppercase
        return word.toUpperCase();
    });
}
//TEST
var text = "Old MacDonald had a farm\nE-I-E-I-O\nAnd on this farm he had a cow\nE-I-E-I-O\nWith a moo-moo here\nAnd a moo-moo there\nHere a moo, there a moo\nEverywhere a moo-moo\nOld McDonald had a farm\nE-I-E-I-O ";
console.log(selectiveUpperCase(text));
```

Comment: One problem with this answer is that it will match a sole `"Mac"` as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes a string prefix to be `one capital letter character` followed by `one or more small letter characters` followed by `one capital letter character` and always at the beginning of the whole word.

The prefix will be retained as it is and the rest will be capitalized.

```js
const input = [
  "McDonald",
  "MacDonald",
  "Mcdonald",
  "mcDonald",
  "mcdonald"
];

// Function for converting to special uppercase
const specialUpperCase = function(item) {
  // Find prefix (one or more lower case characters between upper case character - at the beginning)
  const match = item.match(/^[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z]/);
  if (match) {
    // If prefix, capitalize only the remaining
    return match[0] + item.substr(match[0].length).toLocaleUpperCase();
  }
  // If no prefix, capitalize the whole string
  return item.toLocaleUpperCase();
};

const output = input.map(specialUpperCase);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 version with RegEx, you can try below function replaceStr()

```
const replaceStr = str => str.replace(/(^[A-Z])([a-z]{1,2})(.+)/,
    (_, p1, p2, p3) => p1.toUpperCase() + p2 + p3.toUpperCase());
```