# Protecting Punctuation in Custom Uppercase-Conversion Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function func1(word) {
    matches = word.match(/([A-Z][a-z]+[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]*)/g);
    if (!matches || matches.length === 1) {
        return word.toUpperCase(); }
        else return func2(matches) }
function func2(matched) {
    x = (matches.length) - 1;
    matches[x] = matches[x].toUpperCase();
    return matches.join('');
     }
function func3(isolated) {
    output = isolated.split(/\s/);
 output2 = [];
  for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
      output2.push(func1(output[i])); }
  output = output2.join(' ');
return output;
}
```

The idea is to convert things to uppercase, rendering McGee, McIntosh, etc as McGEE, McINTOSH, etc. Resulted from this thread here: [JavaScript Convert Names to Uppercase, Except Mc/Mac/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942644/javascript-convert-names-to-uppercase-except-mc-mac-etc/)

Initially it was destroying all punctuation, because it didn't fit in with the matches so it just vanished into thin air. So I added the punctuation into the regular expression on line two.

Unfortunately, I then came across the word "Free-Throw", which renders as "Free-THROW" instead of "FREE-THROW". Under the old code it rendered as "FreeTHROW", which isn't any better.

Is there a way I can tackle this other than carefully-phrased inputs? It's for an After Effects expression so there aren't any users to deal with but I'd rather be able to include that hyphen, and if a double-barreled McSomething shows up (McGee-Smith for example) I won't have much choice.

Comment: How long is the list of words you want to keep as lowercase? If it's only a few words, like Mc and Mac, a simple `'mcdo'.toUpperCase().replace( /MC/, 'Mc' );` would already suffice.

Comment: I need it to handle both MacDonald and Mackinnon, and both DeVries and Devon, Dennis, etc, so that's a no-go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment suggesting limited scope is correct, just the wrong way around: rather than defining which prefixes to handle I can easily define punctuation to protect. Dashes and apostrophes are the only characters I really have to worry about appearing mid-word, and dashes are always going to be between "words" within a word.

So instead of all-capsing the last match to the regular expression, I now all-caps both that and any match which ends in a dash.

Apostrophes are removed before the process stars, and re-inserted at the same index after capitalisation is complete.

```
function func1(word) {
    filter = word.indexOf("’");
    word = word.replace("’","");
    matches = word.match(/([-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:"“”;'’<>?,.\/]*[A-Z][a-z]+[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:"“”;'’<>?,.\/]*)/g);
    if (!matches || matches.length === 1) {
        func2out = word.toUpperCase();
    if (filter >= 0){
    func2out = [func2out.slice(0,filter), "’", func2out.slice(filter)].join('');
    }
    return func2out;}
        else return func2(matches) }
function func2(matched) {
    for(x = 0; x < matches.length; x++) {
        if (matches[x].indexOf('-') >= 0 || (x == (matches.length-1))) matches[x] = matches[x].toUpperCase(); }
    func2out = matches.join('');
    if (filter >= 0) {
        func2out = [func2out.slice(0,filter), "’", func2out.slice(filter)].join('');
    }
    return func2out;
     }
function func3(isolated) {
    output = isolated.split(/\s/);
 output2 = [];
  for (i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
      output2.push(func1(output[i])); }
  output = output2.join(' ');
return output;
}
```